# How to create partition on my unused space

Tags: partitioning

I am very new to Ubuntu (coming from windows). I setup ubuntu server in a 1TB hard drive where I chose 2gb as /boot.
Now the cockpit is showing I have a partition as /dev/sda3 under type LVM2 member of 997 GB.

Just like windows, I want to have a separate volume where I will put all my media (for jellyfin server) and around 50gb to 100gb as the ubuntu server system space.

It is showing partitions as follows in parted:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  1128MB  1127MB  fat32              boot, esp
 2      1128MB  3276MB  2147MB  ext4
 3      3276MB  1000GB  997GB
```

What should I fix?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Server as I will be running it headless

Comment: Do not know LVM, but lots of questions on expanding default / volume. So installer does not typically use entire volume for / (root). So you can either expand or create more volumes.  sudo lvcreate your new volume(s). Easy to expand, but difficult to shrink, so do not automatically use all space. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm  & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM